# Plot brushing or accessing drawn shape geometry for spatial subsets in Shiny Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, geometry, leaflet

I've been looking at the nice added functionality of [addDrawToolbar](http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-draw) in Leaflet/Shiny, which allows for custom drawing of shapes etc.

But i'm interested in sub-setting spatial data by accessing the geometry of the drawn shape, how is this done? There are some efforts [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/227) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/K-YZAJ20TRw/1haJf9VGCQAJ) but I can't get them to work at any rate.

I thought perhaps that the clever functionality of [plot brush](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-advanced.html) might work with leaflet maps but Joe Cheng [suggested last year](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/L8-4EqAXLx8) that it wasn't in place.

So, are there any developments or workarounds on this? or has anyone managed to access the geometry of a drawn rectangle using addDrawToolbar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `addDrawToolbar` from the  `leaflet.extras` package.

The docs are sparse but this [page](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/blob/d377e540614b83f06b1316e135cfb4cf583e23af/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/draw/draw-bindings.js) has the code for the `Leaflet.draw` shiny bindings. You can look for the lines that have `Shiny.onInputChange` and in your the server part of your app, use the corresponding `input$event` to get the data passed to the `Shiny.onInputChange`.

Here's a minimal example, you can draw polygons around cities and the names of the cities in the polygon will be displayed below the map:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

cities <- structure(list(AccentCity = c("Saint Petersburg", "Harare", "Qingdao", 
                                        "Addis Abeba", "Xian", "Anshan", "Rongcheng", "Kinshasa", "New York", 
                                        "Sydney", "Lubumbashi", "Douala", "Bayrut", "Luanda", "Ludhiana"
), Longitude = c(30.264167, 31.0447222, 120.371944, 38.749226, 
                 108.928611, 122.99, 116.364159, 15.3, -74.0063889, 151.205475, 
                 27.466667, 9.7, 35.5097222, 13.233174, 75.85), Latitude = c(59.894444, 
                                                                             -17.8177778, 36.098611, 9.024325, 34.258333, 41.123611, 23.528858, 
                                                                             -4.3, 40.7141667, -33.861481, -11.666667, 4.0502778, 33.8719444, 
                                                                             -8.836804, 30.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
                                                                             ), .Names = c("AccentCity", "Longitude", "Latitude"))



cities_coordinates <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cities[,c("Longitude","Latitude")],cities)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  textOutput("selected_cities")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(0,0,2) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      addMarkers(data=cities,lat=~Latitude,lng=~Longitude,label=~AccentCity) %>%
      addDrawToolbar(
        targetGroup='draw',
        polylineOptions=FALSE,
        markerOptions = FALSE,
        circleOptions = TRUE)  %>%
      addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c('draw'), options =
                         layersControlOptions(collapsed=FALSE)) 
  })

  output$selected_cities <- renderText({
    #use the draw_stop event to detect when users finished drawing
    req(input$mymap_draw_stop)
    print(input$mymap_draw_new_feature)
    feature_type <- input$mymap_draw_new_feature$properties$feature_type

    if(feature_type %in% c("rectangle","polygon")) {

      #get the coordinates of the polygon
      polygon_coordinates <- input$mymap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]

      #transform them to an sp Polygon
      drawn_polygon <- Polygon(do.call(rbind,lapply(polygon_coordinates,function(x){c(x[[1]][1],x[[2]][1])})))

      #use over from the sp package to identify selected cities
      selected_cities <- cities_coordinates %over% SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(drawn_polygon),"drawn_polygon")))

      #print the name of the cities
      cities[which(!is.na(selected_cities)),"AccentCity"]
    } else if(feature_type=="circle") {
      #get the coordinates of the center of the cirle
      center_coords <- matrix(c(input$mymap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]],input$mymap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[2]]),ncol=2)

      #calculate the distance of the cities to the center
      dist_to_center <- spDistsN1(cities_coordinates,center_coords,longlat=TRUE)

      #select the cities that are closer to the center than the radius of the circle
      cities[dist_to_center < input$mymap_draw_new_feature$properties$radius/1000,"AccentCity"]
    }


  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit: 
Added support in case the user draws a circle.

Comment: once again thanks for your input on a Shiny issue. I have indeed being using the addDrawToolbar from the leaflet.extras package (I think i linked it). I have been struggling with extracting geometry but i'll have a work through your example.

Comment: Hi @NicE this example worked realy well. How would you do it when you draw a circle instead of a rectangle? With : `circleOptions= drawCircleOptions(showRadius = T)` Since a Circle is not a Polygon right?

Comment: @NicE, in the man of `drawCircleOptions` is an option [link](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/blob/master/R/drawOptions.R) to draw the area of the circle  in m², ha or km². Do you know how to add a parameter that shows the drawn circle in m² instead of ha?

Comment: I had to add `library(sp)`. Do newer versions of these libraries add `SpatialPointsDataFrame` to the global namespace or was this left out?

Comment: @NicE I think you should edit your answer to add `library(sp)`

Answer (score 2):

drawing on and adapting NicE's answer above (accepted), this is what I did to subset and zonal sum a raster, using a drawn rectangle.

Crucially i had to swap over 
`drawn_polygon <- Polygon(do.call(rbind,lapply(polygon_coordinates,function(x){**c(x[[2]][1],x[[1]][1]**)})))` to `drawn_polygon <- Polygon(do.call(rbind,lapply(polygon_coordinates,function(x){**c(x[[1]][1],x[[2]][1]**)})))` to make the extract work, otherwise the extent was the wrong way around.

```
leaf.proj <- "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
LL <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

r <- raster("myraster.tif")

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  textOutput("selected_cities")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(0,0,4) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      addRasterImage(r,project=FALSE, layerId="rasimg") %>%
      addDrawToolbar(
        targetGroup='draw',
        polylineOptions=FALSE,
        markerOptions = FALSE,
        circleOptions = FALSE,
        editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()))%>%
        addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c('draw'), options =
                         layersControlOptions(collapsed=FALSE)) 
  })

  output$rastersum <- renderText({
    #use the draw_stop event to detect when users finished drawing
    req(input$mymap_draw_stop)

    # get the coordinates of the polygon and make SpatialPolygons object
    polygon_coordinates <- input$mymap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]

    drawn_polygon <- Polygon(do.call(rbind,lapply(polygon_coordinates,function(x){c(x[[1]][1],x[[2]][1])})))
    sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(drawn_polygon),"drawn_polygon")))

    # set coords as latlong then transform to leaflet projection
    proj4string(sp) <- LL
    polyre <- spTransform(sp, leaf.proj)

    e <- extract(r,polyre)
    sum(unlist(e),na.rm=T)

  })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

i included `editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions())` to allow me to delete the drawn polygon but ideally i want it to auto delete when i draw a new one, which i will build in at some point.

Comment: Hi @Sam you should add `singleFeature = T` to `addDrawToolbar`

Comment: that's a great suggestion, thanks @M. Kooi If you've any advice on removing a conditonalPanel with the map.id+'_draw_deletestop listener, i'd be grateful!!

Comment: You are welcome. To be honest I dont know exactly how to do that. I posted a similiar question [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528400/plot-brushing-or-accessing-drawn-shape-geometry-for-spatial-subsets-in-shiny-lea/42536601?noredirect=1#comment72291992_42536601[link] yesterday about drawing shapes in a leaflet map @NicE suggested me to look at this post.