# Building SpatialLine from drawn feature in Leaflet/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, polyline

I would like to build a SpatialLine object (to assess against a raster) from a draw event in Leaflet & Shiny. I am using the addDrawToolbar from leaflet.extras.

[I have done this with a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528400/plot-brushing-or-accessing-drawn-shape-geometry-for-spatial-subsets-in-shiny-lea) and thought the transition would be simple but apparently not, i have tried using (and variations of):

```
# get the coordinates of the drawn line
line_coordinates <- input$mymap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]

# transform them to an sp line
drawn_line <- Line(do.call(rbind,lapply(line_coordinates,function(x){c(x[[1]][1],x[[2]][1])})))
```

but that errors out with NA errors or subscript out of bounds.

The following does not produce an error in app:

```
# remove the [[1]] subscript
line_coordinates <- input$rasmap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates

# list to matrix of coordinates for Line
raw <- as.numeric(as.character(do.call(rbind,line_coordinates)))
raw <- do.call(rbind,lapply(line_coordinates,function(x){c(x[1],x[2])}))
```

but when i progess to:

```
# make Line object
drawn_line <- Line(raw)
Warning: Error in .local: cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix

# or
drawn_line <- Line(as.numeric(raw))
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

But every which way i form this, i have "cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix" or "unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"numeric"’"

Answer (score 3):

I think [**mapedit**](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit) in combination with **sf** can help you here. Here's a small example (which obviously isn't strictly reproducible as you can draw whatever you want). `editMap` returns a simple features object of class `sf` which can then be converted to a sp object.

```
library(mapedit)
library(sf)

drawn = editMap() # zoom to where you wanna draw and draw a line
head(drawn) # a sf LINESTRING object

Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
    geometry type:  LINESTRING
    dimension:      XY
    bbox:           xmin: 3.8232 ymin: 46.4076 xmax: 9.0088 ymax: 48.8936
    epsg (SRID):    4326
    proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
      X_leaflet_id feature_type                       geometry
    1           81     polyline LINESTRING(4.5483 46.9803, ...

drawn_sp = as(drawn, "Spatial") # to convert the LINESTRING to a SpatialLinesDataFrame object.
```

In case you want to leverage this functionality inside your own shiny app, have a look at http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/06/09/mapedit_0-2-0.html#shiny-modules where @timelyportfolio provides an example of usage of `editMap` inside shiny.

Comment: cheers Tim, i need to have a look at what your developing with draw tools

Answer (score 1):

leaflet.extras author here. The object returned to the Shiny event is  GeoJSON on the JavaScript side which I think comes to the R side as a list. If you want a spatial object from it consider geojson/geojsonio pkgs to convert the list to sp/sf format.
Tim's suggestion of using mapedit is also a good one. mapedit was exclusively developed to aid in interactive GIS operations like the one you're trying to do. leaflet.extras provides the low level underpinnings for it, but mapedit provides a much richer UX.

Comment: On that geojson note, `sf::st_read` can also read these geojson lists. This is what we use in mapedit.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I will begin to look into geojson packages to convert to sp format. I'm happy i managed it with raw R code but it'll be worth trying out geojson and mapedit. Ta!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had a bit of success;

the drawn feature inside addDrawToolbar from leaflet.extras looks like this:

```
# line feature of 3 vertices
line_coords <- input$rasmap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates
print(line_coords)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] -3.214188

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 54.55634

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] -3.213501

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 54.53383

[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] -3.185349

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 54.53323

class(line_coords)
"list"

# then rbind the list into a matrix, all fine
raw <- do.call(rbind,line_coords)

print(raw)
    [,1]      [,2]    
[1,] -3.214188 54.55634
[2,] -3.213501 54.53383
[3,] -3.185349 54.53323

class(raw)
[1] "matrix"
```

All would seem fine but the error "Error in .local: cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix" still occurs if you perform Line(raw) on the above matrix.

A look at str(raw) reveals:

```
str(raw)
List of 6
 $ : num -3.21
 $ : num -3.21
 $ : num -3.19
 $ : num 54.6
 $ : num 54.5
 $ : num 54.5
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 3 2
NULL
```

Now, i dont really know why that has occurred, a matrix of lists. When the above actions are performed on a standard list of lists, it does not happen;

```
g <- list(list(322000,512000),list(323000,512000),list(325000,514000))
co <- do.call(rbind,g)
str(co)
num [1:3, 1:2] 322000 323000 325000 512000 512000 514000
```

Changing it back to numeric (by column), will fix it;

```
raw <- apply(raw, 2,as.numeric)
str(raw)
num [1:3, 1:2] -3.19 -3.2 -3.17 54.54 54.52 54.51
```

And i can go on to form the Line(raw) object and eventually the spatial object and perform extracts on underlying raster surfaces etc.

Anyway, i hope this is helpful to others in the future.